# Representations of orthogonal groups vs representations of reflection groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space and $O(V)$ the orthogonal group of $V$.
Let $G$ be a (say, finite) reflection group on $V$, regarded as a subgroup of $O(V)$ ($G< O(V)$.) Let
us denote by $R$ a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $O(V)$.

Question: Which irreducible finite dimensional representations $R$ of $O(V)$ remain irreducible, when regarded as $G$-modules?

I am interested in a clean argument for general V, not the cases like $O(2)$ or $O(3)$. The base field of $V$ should be ${\mathbb R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You may be asking for too much in this broad formulation, since a finite reflection group might embed as a subgroup of many orthogonal groups.   Aside from this, it would be helpful to specify the field here, or at least clarify whether you mean "real reflection group" (there being many more "complex reflection groups" to consider).